# Bouncy Castle, Crypto++, Elliptic Curve Crypto (ECC), failing to decode

Tags: c#, .net, bouncycastle, crypto++

We've got a C++ solution using the ECC part of the Crypto++ library but are having to move across to a .NET solution. Due to the minimal documentation for Microsoft's ECC code I;m currently experimenting with the slightly less minimally documented Bouncy Castle library (at least there is source code available). I've got encryption and decryption using BC working fine; decrypting data already encrypted with Crypto++ is proving somewhat more problematic.

My latest issue is that when I try to decrypt a string I'm getting an "IMac codes failed to equal" exception. Does BC add some sort of MAC to the cipher text? Any one know what could be causing this?

Thanks,
Patrick

Comment: How can you ask a question such as yours and provide absolutely zero code? You can get that exception in the IESEngine class and, so evidently you are using ECIES. And yes, IES does compute a MAC. Is your Crypto++ code using IES?

Comment: I'm asking about what bouncy castle does, not what my code does... Thanks for the hint about IES, that's what I needed to know :)

Comment: Did you get it working? You should post the working ECIES code to come full circle on this question :)

Comment: Sorry Sid, I no longer work for the same company and so don't have access to the code and can't remember what I did to get it working :(.

Comment: I know its a late answer, but this is a good question that should have gotten some attention.

Answer (score 3):

> My latest issue is that when I try to decrypt a string I'm getting an "IMac codes failed to equal" exception.

This message does not appear to be part of the current BC distro:

```
$ cd bouncy-castle-153
$ grep -IR "IMac codes failed to equal" *
$
```

It does appear to be part of someone's GitHub; see [PassKit IesEngine.cs](https://github.com/Redth/PassKitSharp/blob/master/PassKitSharp/Crypto/crypto/engines/IesEngine.cs).

It may have been part of a past BC distro.

---

> Does BC add some sort of MAC to the cipher text?

The name `IesEngine.cs` tells me its an [Integrated Encryption Scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_Encryption_Scheme). They are not well known and often not used, but they are *very* good schemes. They combine a lot of primitives into one, and that makes it easy to use correctly and hard to use incorrectly. More technically, the are [IND-CCA2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ciphertext_indistinguishability) which is a strong notion of security.

There are two types of schemes I am aware. The first is an IES over integers, and the second is an IES over elliptic curves. The one over integers is also known as [Discrete Logarithm Integrated Encryption Scheme](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Discrete_Logarithm_Integrated_Encryption_Scheme), and the one over elliptic curves is usually called [Elliptic Curve Integrated Encryption Scheme](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_Integrated_Encryption_Scheme). Libraries like Crypto++ and Bouncy Castle provides both of them.

To get back to your question, one of the things an integrated encryption scheme provides is a MAC over the ciphertext.

---

> Any one know what could be causing this?

Unfortunately, there are a number of things that could be causing this. Most IES are incompatible due to each committee tweaking a scheme. To make matters worse, I have never seen a set of test vectors published. You have to work hard at getting things to interoperate.

In the case of Crypto++ and Bouncy Castle, each suffered a mild bug because there were no test vectors, so each did things a little differently. That meant the ECIES schemes did not interoperate well (or more correctly, at all). You can read about the details at [Bouncy Castle Patch](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_Integrated_Encryption_Scheme) on the Crypto++ wiki.

Moving forward, Crypto++ 5.7 *will* interop with Bouncy Castle 1.54 out of the box. In the future, the classes needed for BC will be documented at the [Crypto++ wiki](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_Integrated_Encryption_Scheme) and the [Crypto++ manual](http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/struct_e_c_i_e_s.html).

Answer (score 0):

Please note, that the Crypto++ 5.6.3 bouncy castle patch mentioned above will only work with bouncy castle versions prior to 1.53.

For newer versions you can either tweak the Crypto++ patch to allow for 8 byte Mac or use the OldECIES class on the java side for interoperability.